# How to read a windows registry file using java?

Tags: java, registry

Is there any Java library available to handle the **windows registry file *(.reg)***.Like read and write ***KEYS, SUBKEYS*** and ***DATA*** from an selected registry file.

**NOTE:** There is solutions available to handle the Windows registry by java. But the needed is to reading registry values, keys and data from (.reg) extension file not directly from registry.

Comment: @KhanAbdulrehman The problem solution suggest how to read and write a windows registry, my question clearly says how to handle Windows registry file (.reg) extension

Answer (score 0):

operation windows registry can use Preferences, jRegistry.

read or write *.reg file may be write it yourself.